# Java regex starting with exactly one backslash

Tags: java, regex

This is my current regex:

```
(?<=\\)foobar
```

I want to match on parts of strings that have foobar and start with EXACTLY ONE backslash.

For example, the pattern should match on `"\foobar"` but it should not match on `"\\foobar"` which it currently is. How can I modify my regex to implement this?

Comment: @user2864740 It needs to contain `foobar`, so probably `^\\[^\\]?.*foobar` or `^\\[^\\]*foobar`? Not clear if backslashes in places other than the second (e.g. `\baz\asdffoobar` are allowed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write this regular expression as follows: `(?<!\\)\\foobar`. This matches `\foobar` that is not immediately preceded by a backslash.

Comment: `^\\[^\\]*foobar` is almost working but when I type `"foobar\foobar\\foobar"` it doesnt change it whereas it should give me `"foobarREPLACED\\foobar"`

Comment: @Ogen OK, I think I understand your exact request now. Let me formulate a new regex.

Comment: @Ogen Should `\\\foobar` be matched, or only cases with exactly one backslash?

Comment: With exactly one backslash

Comment: What would the raw java string look like, Im having trouble getting it to work eventhough the regex works in online regex tools ive checked...

Comment: When writing it as a Java string literal, you just double the backslashes: `"(?<!\\\\)\\\\foobar"`.  So it's *four* backslashes for every *one* literal backslash that you want to match.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do:

```
"^[\\\\]{1}foobar"
```

The above will look for exactly one `\` at the beginning, and then 'foobar' afterwards.

The reason you need four backslashes is because `\` is an escape character for both regex *and* Java. This means that `\\\\` after Java escaping becomes `\\` which is then escaped by regex to produce the `\`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

When you write a regular expression in a Java string, you have to escape the backslashes *for Java*. So a regex that matches a literal backslash needs four: two to escape it for the regex, and another two to escape those for Java.